# ayuda login android studio, no me muestra valores de $user por que no es un JSONobject

Tags: php, android, mysqli

**Código PHP.**

```
  <?php
 require('conexion.php');

 $User=$_POST['User'];
 $Pass=$_POST['Pass'];
$sql="SELECT User,Pass,TipoUsuario FROM tb_usuario WHERE User=? AND 
  Pass=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if ($stmt->execute(array($User,$Pass))) {
    while ($user= $stmt-> fetch() ) {
             $user["User"];
             $user["Pass"];
             $user["TipoUsuario"];
    }
    // Exito en el Logeo
    print json_encode(
        array(
            'estado' => '1',
            'mensaje' => 'Logeo exitoso',
            'User'=>$user["User"],
            'Pass'=>$user["Pass"],
            'TipoUsuario'=>$user["TipoUsuario"]
            )
    );
} else {
    print json_encode(
        array(
            'estado' => '2',
            'mensaje' => 'Favor de  verificar  si su Usuario  o contraseña  son correctas')
    );
}
```

?>

**Este es  mi código Android(JAVA).**

```
    private void loginUser( final String User, final String Pass) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String cancel_req_tag = "login";
    showLoadingDialog("Ingresando  Login.....");
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.URL_LOG, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            try {
                hideLoadingDialog();
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                String estado= jObj.getString("estado");

                if (estado.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    String user = jObj.getString("User");
                    String TipoUsuario=jObj.getString("TipoUsuario");
                    // Launch User activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Login.this,mymenu.class);
                    intent.putExtra("User", user);
                    intent.putExtra("TipoUsuario",TipoUsuario);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {

                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideLoadingDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("User",User);
            params.put("Pass", Pass);
            return params;
        }

    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq,cancel_req_tag);
}
```

**Este es el  error que  me muestra el Logcat**  Los valores están Vacíos.

```
   8 1164-1545/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
  05-18 12:42:52.225 3019-3019/com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql D/Login: Register Response: {"estado":"1","mensaje":"Logeo exitoso","User":null,"Pass":null,"TipoUsuario":null}
   05-18 12:42:52.272 1550-1566/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql/.mymenu (has extras)} from uid 10059 on display 0

   05-18 12:42:52.277 1550-1566/system_process V/WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{4f95492 token=Token{2cfa0a1d ActivityRecord{75b42f4 u0 com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql/.mymenu t2112}}} to stack=1 task=2112 at 1
  05-18 12:42:52.288 1550-1848/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@10d9ae63 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@2b836327
 05-18 12:42:52.397 3019-3032/com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.611ms
```

Comment: Para mejor respuesta a esta pregunta te sugiero agregues la respuesta que se obtiene al consultar el .php. @Sofia

Comment: @Jorgesys,  acabo de  agregar  el error que me manda  en el Logcat, me  dice  que  los  valores están  vacíos le  he estado moviendo al código PHP   pero  no logro solucionarlo

Comment: ok al menos ya sabemos la estructura que debe parsear tu código, pero verifica que sucede en el .php

Comment: @Jorgesys disculpa, hay alguna manera de contactarte? Sobre unas dudas de conceptos de android?

Comment: @sioesi hey tu eres uno de los expertos en android ( y otros), si claro, pues si deseas realiza un room en el chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estas agregando en la respuesta los datos que quieres obtener:

```
 // Exito en el Logeo
print json_encode(
    array(
        'estado' => '1',
        'mensaje' => 'Logeo exitoso'),
        'User' => $user["User"]),
        'TipoUsuario' => $user["TipoUsuario"])
);
```

Y en tu codigo Java:

```
String user = jObj.getString("User");
String TipoUsuario = jObj.getString("TipoUsuario");
```

Edito:

No estoy completamente familiarizado con PHP por lo que podría estar diciendo una barbaridad, pero la variable "user" la declaras como una condición del bucle while, ¿Es accesible fuera del bucle?
Prueba de esta manera a ver si eso soluciona el problema:

```
 <?php
   require('conexion.php');

  $User=$_POST['User'];
  $Pass=$_POST['Pass'];
  $sql="SELECT User,Pass,TipoUsuario FROM tb_usuario WHERE User=? AND Pass=?";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  if ($stmt->execute(array($User,$Pass))) {
    //almacenas el resultado en la variable user (supongo que no necesitas usar while, ya que el usuario y pass serán únicos)
    $user = $stmt->fetch();

     // Exito en el Logeo
     print json_encode(
         array(
             'estado' => '1',
             'mensaje' => 'Logeo exitoso',
             'User'=>$user["User"],
             'Pass'=>$user["Pass"],
             'TipoUsuario'=>$user["TipoUsuario"]
             )
     );
 } else {
     print json_encode(
         array(
             'estado' => '2',
             'mensaje' => 'Favor de  verificar  si su Usuario  o contraseña  son correctas')
     );
 }
```

Comment: hice  los cambios que me indicaste  pero  aún no logro solucionar  mi error, le he estado moviendo al código PHP  por que  me dice  que  los valores están  vacíos, lo chequé  en mi navegador  los  valores que  me  devuelve  es verdad son nulos

Comment: Haz que el php imprima en pantalla el user, pass y tipousuario en el bucle while y ejecuta desde el navegador, ahi podrás ver si el error viene de la consulta SQL

Answer (score 0):

A partir de la respuesta que obtienes:

```
 {"estado":"1","mensaje":"Logeo exitoso","User":null,"Pass":null,"TipoUsuario":null}
```

tu código para parsear este objeto debe funcionar correctamente,

```
   try {
        hideLoadingDialog();
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
        String estado= jObj.getString("estado");

        if (estado.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            String user = jObj.getString("User");
            String TipoUsuario=jObj.getString("TipoUsuario");
            // Launch User activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Login.this,mymenu.class);
            intent.putExtra("User", user);
            intent.putExtra("TipoUsuario",TipoUsuario);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {

            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

El problema es que el .php no esta entregando valores para "User" , "Pass" y "TipoUsuario"!